# How to set defaultValue using react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, input, textinput, native-base

I am using input from native base and I am unable to set a default value for the input field.I am testing on an IOS device. Following is my code for input:

```js
<Item floatingLabel>
  <Label>Email</Label>
  <Input
    onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
    defaultValue={this.props.navigation.state.params.email}
    getRef={c => (this._inputEmail = c)}
    onSubmitEditing={event => {
      this._inputPhone._root.focus();
    }}
    returnKeyType="next"
    keyboardType="email-address"
    autoCapitalize="none"
    autoCorrect={false}
  />
</Item>
```

I have used it before in a TextInput and it works fine. I don't understand why it isn't working for input.
Any help or suggestion is appreciated.Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not sure how your `Input` component looks like, but seems you are not passing props down to `TextInput`, because `defaultValue` is available on `TextInput` component.

Comment: @TheReason I am using the following as a default Value :- defaultValue={this.props.navigation.state.params.email}

Comment: @TuấnTrầnDuy in the document it says something like Input: React Native TextInput I suppose it has all the functionality that the text input has with added benifits

Comment: Can you add code for your `Input` component?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know NativeBase doesn't have a defaultValue prop on the Input, but you could just use a combination of the onChangeText and the value prop like this:

```
<Input
onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
value={this.state.email}
getRef={c => (this._inputEmail = c)}
onSubmitEditing={event => {
    this._inputPhone._root.focus();
}}
returnKeyType="next"
keyboardType="email-address"
autoCapitalize="none"
autoCorrect={false}
/>
```

Set the default value in the constructor or with setState in componentDidMount()

Comment: Thank you so much. Actual the flow of my app is I am clicking on a button for edit and then on edit screen I want to prepopulate the Input fields with data.

Comment: Set the onPress action for the button to `setState({email: value, ...});` and take the value from your redux state(e.g. `email: this.props.navigation.state.params.email`), so you are good to go ;)